# Callback to Cordova plugin from Objective C delegate

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova, ionic-framework

Situation: I'm building a cordova plugin to connect an existing iOS library with Ionic. The base mapping of methods is done and working, means I can call the iOS methods via Angular methods and getting success/error callbacks.

Problem: There's a login method which is called, and appropriate delegate methods (e.g. userDidLoginWithSuccess) are called afterwards. Callback from the login method to the cordova plugin is easy, but I need to somehow callback from the delegate method, in order to let the Ionic app know if the user was logged in successfully or not.

Any thoughts on this? Thanks.

PS: I checked this post, which didn't help, although it's a similar question. [Phonegap - Send message to Javascript from Objective-c in a plugin delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810420/phonegap-send-message-to-javascript-from-objective-c-in-a-plugin-delegate)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On your .h create a property callbackId that you will use to store the callback identifier of the plugin

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* callbackId;
```

Then, on your plugin method, store the callbackId on the property you created.

```
self.callbackId = command.callbackId;
```

and finally, on the delegate send the plugin result using the callbackId

```
CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"string result"];
[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:self.callbackId];
```

Comment: Thanks @jcesarmobile, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there an example anyone can point to with this implemented?

Comment: I've done the same for Swift. I've connected to the Swift code, and can get the code to fire off. It's an iBeacon plugin, so plenty of delegates. Anyone have any suggestions on how to get callbacks using Swift? I tried using this method, but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: You can try sending a no result and set keepcallback to true. Some objective-c code self.pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_NO_RESULT];
        [self.pluginResult setKeepCallbackAsBool:YES];

Comment: Of course, I solved it right after I post a comment/question. In the "listener function", you just make sure the plugin result has a result of CDVCommandStatus_NO_RESULT and in the next line set the plugin's "setKeepCallback" to true. Then you do the rest as show in this answer.

Comment: I should've refreshed my browser before commenting to see your response @jcesarmobile. Thank you!

Comment: @Bennybear, I implemented the same, but the callback reached .js file only for the first time. For the next subsequent delegate method calls, it never reached js file again. Please help.