# Verifone e355 iOS integration - unable to trigger barcode scanner with soft mode

Tags: ios, point-of-sale, verifone

I'm working in a POS(iPad) application where we are using Verifone E355 for payments. Now I have a requirement to trigger the barcode scanner of verifone e355 device(https://www.verifone.com/en/us/devices/mpos/e355) through software from iPad.

VMF(Verifone mobile framework) iOS sdk is being used to communicate calls with E355.

I have followed the framework docs and initialised the barcode scanner API. To activate the barcode scanner and scan the below code snippet is used.

I always get a return of -9 (which is an error code, description as per docs - **Value returned when command was sent when device is connected but not connection not initialized**) upon calling startScan and sendTriggerEvent: api's.

```
[self.barcodeScanner initDevice];
int startScanResult = [self.barcodeScanner startScan]
int setSoftTrigger = [self.barcodeScanner sendTriggerEvent:true];
```

The above code block is what I have tried till now. If anyone has experience working with e355 integration, please help out here.

Answer (score 1):

you need to confirm to the delegate of VFIBarcode and once you scan you will get response from barcodeScanData delegate method.

Comment: I had set the delegate and had delegate methods implemented too. What I missed was adding bluetooth protocols in info.plist file. So the sdk couldn't establish a session with the E355. Thanks for your response.

Comment: I haven't tried it. You can contact verifone support team for sdk related help, they seem to respond quickly.

Comment: because I am making connection over wifi it works for iOS native app but I had created Cordova Plugin for VMF framework and integrated to Cordova app but delegate methods not being called from plugin any idea? followed these comments from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32719016/callback-to-cordova-plugin-from-objective-c-delegate but no luck.

Comment: Seems this is related to cordova bridge. If you know how to create a custom plugin on your own and still facing some issue please raise a question with sample code and explain whatever you have done. Else explore on creating a custom plugin for Cordova in depth, for which you can get a lot of references in internet.